# How to get some of the Azure dashboard items in my Azure Monitor Workbook

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

When using Azure Portal and browsing the resources you have the option to pin a lot of overviews to your dashboard.
Some of those overviews I would like to add to my workbook, but I can't find the underlying queries.
How can I do this?
I'm interested in for example the Application Map, the Memory working set, the Advisor Score.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything supported on azure dashboards are supported in workbooks.  Dashboard parts are code created by various extension teams, that can't necessarily live inside workbooks.

- If they are based on Azure Metrics, almost all of those can be used in workbooks (open them in the full metrics view, then in the share menu there's an option for "send to workbook" which can add those metrics steps to a workbook)
- If they're based on Log Analytics queries, there's also a "Send to workbooks" item in their share menu that can send the contents of the query window to a workbook as well. (click a logs pin to open it in full logs view, then use the "pin to" menu and choose "send to workbook" to send the queries to a workbook)

Pretty much anything else would have to be manually reproduced inside workbooks. If the parts query ARM, you'd use that data source, things like App Map are their own entire features that don't simplify enough to currently be used directly in a workbook.

Comment: Thanks John for the clarification. I already noticed the 'Send to workbook" option.   
I was asking for the dashboard parts that don't have that button.   
I will look for an other solution.